# How to deploy Crystal Report that uses push method (xsd file dataset datasource)

Tags: crystal-reports, xsd, dataset, datasource

Can anyone suggest best method for what I want to accomplish? I have an VS 2008 asp.net(MVC) web app and I am using Crystal Reports as my report engine. My app accepts parms from a form and calls a SQL Server stored proc to create a Dataset which I set as the datasource for the report. The report was created using an XSD file as a schema template. The XSD was created by dragging my Stored proc from the Server Explorer onto the XSD window in VS 2008. All works well in dev with my report displaying with the expected data. My question /concern is deploying this to the web server. A) Do I need to copy my XSD files to the web server? Is so how will they resolve the path? My site is hosted so I can't created a D:\Datasets folder as I saw somewhere else suggested. B) Is there a way to program this dataset path at runtime? 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I don't have to deploy the xsd file. Reports work fine when deployed.